# Cannot connect Logitech 810 keboard on 13.10

Tags: bluetooth, logitech, wireless-keyboards

I have a Logitech 810 bluetooth key board that I was able to pair when I was running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  After the upgrade to 13.10 it no longer works and the old recipes to get the keyboard connected no longer seem to work.  Has anybody succeeded in getting this keyboard to work in 13.10?

Comment: Actually since posting this question I was able to get it to work by following the directions for a wireless connect using a Mac bluetooth keyboard.  I don't know if the Logitech keyboard will continue to work after I reboot.  I will let you know later.

Comment: More information:  After leaving the computer idle for the night, the next morning the keyboard connection was lost.

Comment: Here is the procedure I use to get a connection, at least temporarily:

Comment: Here is the procedure I use to get a connection, at least temporarily:  sudo apt-get install bluez-compat;  sudo apt-get install bluez-compat; hcitool scan [this command finds the MAC number of the keyboard if it is in discovery mode.}; sudo hidd --connect AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF (where the 6 pairs of characters constitute the MAC number of the keyboard).  However, the keyboard does not stay connected very long before spontaneously disconnecting for no discernible reason.

Comment: OK I think I finally solved this problem.  The solution that seems to be working is documented in the Ubuntu forum Thread: "earlier thread about bluetooth keyboard". In order for the procedure described there to work, you must install the package bluez-hcidump.  This will enable you to use the hcidump -at command.

Comment: Yes! It definitely works and continues to work.  The best step-by-step procedure is found [here](http://blog.chschmid.com/?p=1537).

Answer (score 1):

The clearest step-by-step procedure is posted [here](http://blog.chschmid.com/?p=1537). So for, in the past 24 hours, I have not had any problems with the keyboard connection.

### The below instruction is from the [source](http://blog.chschmid.com/?p=1537).

> 1. Start a terminal (terminal 1)
> 2. Install the tools needed for this walk-through
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install bluez-hcidump bluez-utils blueman
>    ```
> 3. Enable Bluetooth on your Ubuntu machine (you might have a hardware button, don’t forget about that)
> 4. Start the bluetooth manager (blueman) from your start menu, dash, or whatever other way of starting programs your desktop has
> 5. Start another terminal (terminal 2) – yep you’ll need two for this exercise
> 6. Get the K810 into pairing mode by pressing the button on the back of the keyboard and then one of the device buttons on the front
>      (F1-F3). You should see the bluetooth light flashing now.
> 7. In terminal 1 run
>
>    ```
>    hcitool scan
>    ```
>
>    if the K810 is found this should give you something like
>
>    ```
>    Scanning ...
>    xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   Logitech K810
>    ```
> 8. Copy the address of your K810 (that’s the `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`)
> 9. In terminal 2 run
>
>    ```
>    sudo hcidump -at | grep pass
>    ```
> 10. In terminal 1 run
>
>     ```
>     sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>     ```
> 11. In terminal 2 you should now see the passkey which is a number
> 12. Type that code on your K810 followed by enter
> 13. The bluetooth manager should now show the K810.
> 14. In blueman select the K810 and mark it as “trusted”
> 15. Now click on Setup and follow the dialog box.
> 16. Tada, you’re done, you can now close all terminals as well as blueman.

Answer (score 0):

Try BlueZ because Linux is not supported by logitech:

http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/35054